# Gatsby: Creating Pages from Contentful Fields

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

Each of my posts on Contentful has some associated 'categories' with it. For example, one post might contain:

```
major: "HCD"
year: "1st Year"
tools: ["R", "Python", "Wordpress"]
```

These are just fields called `major`, `year` etc. with these values but they are treated as individual categories.
On the website, they are displayed as such:
[image]

I am trying to create a page for each of these categories. For example, if a user clicks on `Photoshop`, they should be taken to a page `tags/photoshop` and all posts containing that tag should be listed out.

Fortunately, I was able to find [this guide](https://dennytek.com/blog/personal-site-with-gatsby-part-7/) to help me do this. However, the guide is not for Contentful data so I'm having a bit of trouble on how to do this. I have created the `tagsTemplate.jsx` and but I'm stuck at creating the actual pages.

For example, this is what I did to try and create pages for `tools`:

My `gatsby-node.js` file looks like this:

```js
const path = require(`path`)
const _ = require('lodash');

exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type contentfulPortfolioDescriptionTextNode implements Node {
      description: String
      major: String
      author: String
      tools: [String]
      files: [ContentfulAsset]
      contact: String
    }
    type ContentfulPortfolio implements Node {
      description: contentfulPortfolioDescriptionTextNode
      gallery: [ContentfulAsset]
      id: ID!
      name: String!
      related: [ContentfulPortfolio]
      slug: String!
      major: String!
      files: [ContentfulAsset]
      author: String!
      tools: [String]!
      year: String!
      thumbnail: ContentfulAsset
      url: String
      contact: String
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    graphql(`
      {
        portfolio: allContentfulPortfolio {
          nodes {
            slug
            tools
          }
        }
      }
    `).then(({ errors, data }) => {
      if (errors) {
        reject(errors)
      }

      if (data && data.portfolio) {
        const component = path.resolve("./src/templates/portfolio-item.jsx")
        data.portfolio.nodes.map(({ slug }) => {
          createPage({
            path: `/${slug}`,
            component,
            context: { slug },
          })
        })
      }
       
      const tools = data.portfolio.nodes.tools;
      const tagTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/tagsTemplate.js`);
      let tags = [];
      // Iterate through each post, putting all found tags into `tags`
      tags = tags.concat(tools);
       // Eliminate duplicate tags
      tags = _.uniq(tags);
      
       // Make tag pages
       tags.forEach(tag => {
        createPage({
          path: `/tags/${_.kebabCase(tag)}/`,
          component: tagTemplate,
          context: {
            tag
          },
        });
      });
      
      console.log("Created Pages For" + tags)

      resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

My `tagsTemplate` is minimal right now, since I don't know how to query the data:

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout"

const Tags = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>Tags</div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Tags;
```

The problem: When I visit the page for one of the tags I know exists (like `photoshop`), I get a 404. Why are these pages not being created?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? How can this be generalized for three of my 'categories'?

Comment: Can you debug your `tags` array?

Comment: @FerranBuireu How do I do that? I tried `console.log(tags)` but is shows it as `undefined`. This is while doing the build. I don't know how to debug individual variables afterwards.

Comment: Then you can't create pages from `undefined` variable. What's inside `tools`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu, for each post, tools is an array of strings like `["R", "Python", "Wordpress"]` The top of my post contains an example.

Comment: Your code looks good, since `tags` should be filled with the `tools`. What's the output of: ```tags.forEach(tag => {console.log(tag);createPage({path:`/tags/${_.kebabCase(tag)}/`,component: tagTemplate,context: {tag},});```

Comment: @FerranBuireu, I did that and it is just a blank space. Does that mean there is nothing in `tags` at all?

Comment: [This is one of my entry's JSON response](https://pastebin.com/tbWGp9RV), if it helps to look at the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you said in the comments:

> I tried `console.log(tags)` but is shows it as `undefined`

> I did that and it is just a blank space. Does that mean there is nothing in `tags` at all?

Your contact function looks good, the approach is good since you are adding the `tools` (list of `tags`) into a new array to clean it up and leaving unique values (`uniq`). Once done, you loop through the unique tags and create pages based on that array.

That said, there are a few weak points where your house of cards can fall apart. Your issue start in this line:

```
const tools = data.portfolio.nodes.tools;
```

And propagates through the code.

`nodes` is an array so, to get any value you should do:

```
const tools = data.portfolio.nodes[0].tools;
```

To get the first position and so on...

Since `tools` is never populated, the rest of the code doesn't work.

You can easily fix it looping through the `nodes` and populating your `tags` array with something similar to:

```
  const toolNodes = data.portfolio.nodes;

  const tagTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/tagsTemplate.js`);
  let tags = [];

  // Iterate through each post, putting all found tags into `tags`
  toolNodes.map(toolNode => tags.push(toolNode.tools);
  // if the fetched data is still an array you can do toolNodes.map(toolNode => tags.push(...toolNode.tools);     

   // Eliminate duplicate tags
  tags = _.uniq(tags);
  
   // Make tag pages
   tags.forEach(tag => {
    createPage({
      path: `/tags/${_.kebabCase(tag)}/`,
      component: tagTemplate,
      context: {
        tag
      },
    });
  });
  
  console.log("Created Pages For" + tags)
```

Comment: This works! Except there is one issue. Instead of creating pages for `weaving` and `charcoal` and `web-design` individually, it is creating pages like this: `http://localhost:8000/tags/weaving-charcoal-web-design/`, all in one.

Comment: If for the rest of tags works, your data structure is different for each post and the loop is not generating the same array structure (i.e: `["a", ["b","c","d"]]` instead of `["a", "b", "c","d"]`. Check the fetched data or add a Codesandbox

Comment: In that case, use `toolNodes.map(toolNode => tags.push(...toolNode.tools);`

Comment: Thank you SO much!! That works perfectly. If I may ask one last question on the side, is this `tags` array stored globally? Can I refer to it on another page to list out all the `tools` or is that not possible?

Comment: Additionally, this only works when I initialize an empty array called `tools`. I am guessing that `const toolNodes = data.portfolio.nodes;` contains all nodes, so how is it separating the one called `tools`?

Comment: No, you can't. The scope of the `tags` variable is restricted to the scope of the promise set in the `gatsby-node.js` since the variable is never exported, it will be never visible to the rest of the code. What you can do is to create a custom hook using the `useStaticQuery` (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) that fetches all tags. Then, only calling the custom hook from any component, you'll have available the tags

Comment: Yes, it's the same. It was easy to me to put it that way but yes, it's exactly the same